VS Code ignoring terminal defaultProfile settings
I'm trying to get VS Code to default to zsh but it seems intent on running bash instead.
I'm on a Mac with OS 13.6.7 installed and I'm following along with the advice in this SO thread as well as this GitHub issue. I've updated my settings.json based on that advice:
{
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
        "zsh": {
            "path": "/bin/zsh",
            "args": [
                "-l",
                "-i"
            ]
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled": false
}

But no matter what I do, as soon as I open up a terminal within VS Code and run echo $SHELL, I get /bin/bash. Meanwhile, if I run the same command in an ordinary terminal, I get /bin/zsh.
When I inspect the default profile within the VS Code GUI it shows zsh as the default:

And the terminal view makes it look like it's using zsh but an echo $SHELL says otherwise:

Have read through the VS Code docs and talked to ChatGPT but no luck so far. Any advice?

what is the output of ls /bin/bash (just on the off chance that /bin/bash is a symlink to /bin/zsh)

Honestly, it looks like you are using zsh, just the $SHELL environment variable is /bin/bash

I would generally advise using shell integration unless you have a specific reason not to (I'm not sure why are you are doing this: terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled": false

@topsail if I run ls /bin/bash in my regular terminal or a VS Code terminal, they both output /bin/bash.
For the line "terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled": false, ChatGPT recommended I try adding that line. But even if I remove it echo $SHELL keeps returning /bin/bash in a VS Code terminal.

Have you tried setting your default shell to Zsh using chsh -s $(which zsh)?

ChatGPT is a LLM. I don't think what it says is relevant at all. You are free to try its suggestions, but if they don't work I don't see how it matters what it said. Frankly its just annoying to hear more stories of how it doesn't solve another problem.

Normally on a mac I think zsh would be the default terminal. It seems like you may have done something to override that (somewhere else?) Do you have workspace settings that may overriding user settings?

Just as another try I would recommend not settings these commands yourself but through the settings UI (as shown, for example, here and elsewhere). I don't know if JSON settings are read top to bottom but you are making your default profile osx BEFORE you define the profile osx in the settings ... possibly needs to be put in correct order (?)

Also, just to reiterate - I would not recommend setting use integrated terminal to false. If ChatGPT recommends this, why does it recommend this? Even if it gives you a reason why, how do you know its a good reason?

I've removed the "terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled": false setting. And I ran chsh -s $(which zsh) and my terminal returned chsh: no changes made, which makes sense because I've been seeing zsh in a regular terminal when I run echo $SHELL. I also tried changing the order of properties in my settings.json and set my osx settings at the top but still no luck. My machine is a bit old at this point and there must just be something old/bad lurking in the background. May try reinstalling my OS to get a fresh start.

If you want the SHELL variable to be set, you have to set it. Put into your ~/.zshenv the command
export SHELL==zsh

and unless one of your other startup files resets the variable, you should be fine.
Note: The = is for path name expansion and ensures that the absolute path of your zsh is stored into SHELL.
My guess is that your account is configured with bash as login shell. By the time your VSC is called, SHELL is set to bash, and this is inherited by your zsh.

If you want the SHELL variable to be set, you have to set it. Put into your ~/.zshenv the command
export SHELL==zsh

and unless one of your other startup files resets the variable, you should be fine.
My guess is that your account is configured with bash as login shell. By the time your VSC is called, SHELL is set to bash, and this is inherited by your zsh.
